# Creating INSERT Query dynamically without empty values

Tags: c#

First, I read this: [How to dynamically build an insert command from Datatable in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857368/how-to-dynamically-build-an-insert-command-from-datatable-in-c-sharp)

But this doesn't helped me because i have multiple DataTypes (for example `int`) which can't be `NULL`.

I want that if a value is empty, that this would not be added to the Insert string.

Now: `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES ('val1', '', '', 'val4');`

Goal: `INSERT INTO table (col1, col4) VALUES ('val1','val4');`

Alternative goal: `INSERT INTO (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES ('val1', 'NULL', '0', 'val4');`
*(If integer then replace `NULL` with `0`)*

First I tried to edit the parameter value so if `Length <= 0` then set the value to `NULL`.
But this won't work for an `INTEGER`.

```
cmd.CommandText = sql;

foreach (DataRow row in _dataTable.Rows)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    foreach (DataColumn col in _dataTable.Columns)
    {
        var rowitem = row[col].ToString();
        if (rowitem.Length <= 0)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@{col.ColumnName}", "NULL");
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@{col.ColumnName}", row[col]);
        }
    }
}
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

In my DataBase all tables allows `NULL` so that shouldn't be the problem.
It's just for the Integer.

Then I thought of getting the DataType of `row[col]` so if the datatype is `Int32` then reset `"NULL"` with `"0"`.

But if I want to check the DataType:

```
Debug.WriteLine(row[col].GetType());
```

Im only getting `AllowDBNull`. So thats not the real DataType.

Comment: Because of the `@` which marks the parameter I guess.

Comment: Oh ignore me, I am dumb.  I didnt see the `@`, you are absolutely right.  For some reason my morning brain thought the `@` character was part of the string interpolation syntax

Comment: Do you mean "**all colums** of all tables allow `NULL`"? So why do you want to fill `int` fields with `0` and `string` fields with (the string) `"NULL"` instead of just filling everything with `DBNull.Value` if needed?

Comment: try this
`cmd.Parameters.Add($"@{col.ColumnName}", col.DataType).Value = row[col];`

Comment: @Corak doesn't noticed, that this exists.

Comment: @Pielroja - a field in a table filled with the `string` `"NULL"` is something completely different than it not being filled at all (`NULL` or in this case `DBNull.Value`). And the same goes for a field in a table filled with the valid integer value `0` and not being filled at all. -- also, if this is your actual code, you're only ever inserting the last row of the `_dataTable`.

Comment: @Corak Yea i noticed that i only have the same row. Thing is, it worked before until the error comes ("int cant be 'NULL'") now everything is fine, but its the same row every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value is null (DBNull.Value) then do not add parameter.

```
cmd.CommandText = sql;

foreach (DataRow row in _dataTable.Rows)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    foreach (DataColumn col in _dataTable.Columns)
    {                        
        if(row[col] != DBNull.Value)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@{col.ColumnName}", row[col]);
        }
    }
}
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

In case if you require to know the data type of the column use DataColumn.DataType. For more https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx

If using C#6 or above

```
cmd.CommandText = sql;

foreach (DataRow row in _dataTable.Rows)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    foreach (DataColumn col in _dataTable.Columns)
    {                        
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@{col.ColumnName}", row[col] ?? DBNull.Value);
    }
}
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```